# How to retrieve live Teams Call Transcript?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, transcription

Is there any method available that allows for the generation of live call transcripts without relying on compliance bots?

I am currently exploring options for obtaining live Teams call transcript. I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve compliance bot and can provide the transcripts in a timely manner.

Is there an alternative method for obtaining real-time transcript of Microsoft Teams calls, including participant names and their respective contributions?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Currently there is no way to do this, engineering team is working on a feature to allow bot access real-time transcript. But there is no ETA/Timeline to share.